# Mixing Gremlin, OpenCypher and SPARQL

Tags: graph-databases, amazon-neptune

AWS Neptune being on a lower level a triple-store (presumably a BlazeGraph fork), it can be queried via SPARQL. At the same time, one can use Gremlin and OpenCypher but as far as I can tell these do not access the triple data (and vice versa). That is, it looks like the property graph is separate from the triples. Is this correct or am I missing something obvious? Can one fetch property-graph data with SPARQL, can one query triples with Gremlin/OpenCypher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property Graph and RDF data are stored separately inside of Neptune.  If you write data via the `/sparql` endpoint, it can then only be accessed via SPARQL thereafter.  Similar situation if you write via the `/gremlin` or `/oc` endpoints, although Property Graph data can be simultaneously accessed via either Gremlin or openCypher.

Comment: Any documentation pointer where this is highlighted, I looked around but could not find much in that direction.

Comment: See the "Note" at the bottom of this page:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/get-started-access-graph.html